# React Js how can i update the State after changes? With componentDidUpdate?

Tags: reactjs, axios

Hello i've been trying to implement componentDidUpdate. But i have a problem. But i think im doing some part correct, like i have the If statement required? im pretty sure this worked like 2 hours ago but now it's looping in the console. what am i missing?

I will start by posting the most relevant info from my component. I also have CRUD in my component. The view is updating fine after every change but with a downside of a loop from  componentDidUpdate that wont stop.

i Would appreciate some help on this matter i've tried to do some research, i guess i should not call the API  again? but how can i fix this issue.

i will only post the relevant code from my component.

```
enter code here
```

state = {
productList: [],
statusMsg: "",
};

```
  // READ FROM API
  getDataFromProductsApi() {
    axios
      .get("https://localhost:44366/api/Products/")
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res.data);
        this.setState({
          productList: res.data,
        });
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
        this.setState({ statusMsg: "Error retreiving data" });
        if (axios.isCancel(error)) return;
      });
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getDataFromProductsApi();
  }

  // reupdate the state on Changes
  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    console.warn("changes");
    if (prevState.productList !== this.state.productList) {
      axios.get("https://localhost:44366/api/Products/").then((res) => {
        console.log(res.data);
        this.setState({
          productList: res.data,
        });
      });
    }
  }
```

//Post
axios
.post("https://localhost:44366/api/Products/", this.state)
.then((response) => {
console.log(response);
this.setState({ statusMessage: "Product Added" });
})
.catch((error) => {
console.log(error);
this.setState({ statusMessage: "Something went wrong" });
if (axios.isCancel(error)) return;
});
};

```
  // DELETE FROM API
  deleteProduct = (productId, productName) => {
    if (window.confirm("Are you sure? you want to delete")) {
      axios
        .delete(`https://localhost:44366/api/Products/${productId}`)
        .then((response) => {
          console.log(response);
          this.setState({
            statusMsg: `Product name: ${productName} With the ID: ${productId} was removed!`,
            //updating state to show the changes in view instantly
            //  productList: this.state.productList.filter(
            //  (item) => item.id !== productId
            //),
          });
        });
    }
  };
```

Comment: That `prevState.productList !== this.state.productList` will always `return true` because they are arrays

Comment: i see, how can  i fix this issue?

Comment: Try `JSON.stringify(prevState.productList) == JSON.stringify(this.state.productList)`.
Or lodash equality functions will also be great.

Comment: i dont know what lodash equality is but:D i get error with the Json you meant to replace ifstatement with that?

Comment: no, it will be like `if(JSON.stringify(prevState.productList) == JSON.stringify(this.state.productList))`

It should be inside the `if()`

Comment: tried it something seems to work but. i think the problem starts when the list is empty and i refresh it starts to loop. now when i added this . when i remove an item it delets without refresh but when i add i have to refresh now

Comment: sorry, it should be `if(JSON.stringify(prevState.productList) != JSON.stringify(this.state.productList))`

Comment: it does'nt loop but i doesnt update the state either i have to refresh now after adding and deleting

Comment: May I ask why are you updating the state in the `componentDidUpdate()` instead of directly settings it using `this.setState()`?

Comment: its like the condition never gets true now?

Comment: you can see the "changes" log, but not data?

Comment: exactly. i se the log but it doesnt seem to call the componentdidupdate

Comment: what do u mean now aint i doing this.setstate? u want me to remove the axios call?
i simply just want to refresh the UI without refreshing page manually

Comment: when adding new item or removing, are you updating the `this.state.productList` too?
Can  you show the adding, deleting methods too

Comment: i added them to the original post the POSt/Delete. the post to api is in another component

Comment: my delete function got a code for updating ui which is commented out . but i went for componentdidupdate because i wanted to try updating the ui like that .

Comment: thanks, you need to update the `this.state.productList` using `this.setState()` when adding, updating and deleting, otherwise `prevState.productList ` will always be equal to `this.state.productList` that is why it is not rendering

Comment: how can i do it when adding?. i already have it for Deleting but when adding i dont have the id

Comment: im using thsi filter method when deleting  and it works

  productList: this.state.productList.filter(
              (item) => item.id !== productId

Comment: yeah deleting is correct, adding also can be done using `[...this.state.productList, newProduct]`.
The id can be generated using `uuid`.

Comment: but you don't even have to add a new one correctly, you just need to make sure that the current state of the `this.state.productList` has changed, because that is what causes the component to get new `productList` from the server and update the state.

Comment: even tho the create is in another component and knows nothing about the list?

Comment: yeah, if you are expecting this component to update when you make changes in the other component

Comment: never worked with uuid etc:D

Comment: As I said, you don't even have to actually have a proper ID, you just need to trigger an update, so adding a fake ID would do the trick.
But, if you want to do it properly I suggest, in the server, after making a successful post request to add a new product, return the newly created product as the response, and then add that to the component state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since arrays are objects in JS, two arrays are equal only is they reference the same value(not different instances of that same value).

So using `===` and `!==` to compare arrays would be wrong.

```
console.log([1, 2] === [1, 2])   // returns false

let obj1 = {
    name: 'Disney'
};

let obj2 = {
    name: 'Disney'
}

console.log(obj1 === obj2);    // returns false

console.log([obj1] == [obj2]);  // returns false;
```

So, I guess the problem is here in `(prevState.productList !== this.state.productList)`

You could refer to this answer for more on
[How to compare arrays in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7837456/how-to-compare-arrays-in-javascript)

Comment: i think this is what the answer above says? but i get same result